# Trouble Installing AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I've just add angularJS to my project and I am now trying to add AngularUI  to my project but it's not working correctly. The buttons don't look nice like they are supposed to. My webpage looks like http://postimg.org/image/mzgqlk7mr/

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />
    <link href="menu_source/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>




      <!--
      <div ng-controller="logOut">
    <h4>Single toggle</h4>
    <pre>{{singleModel}}</pre>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
        Single Toggle
    </button>
    -->


    </div>


    <div id="content">
    Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{name}}
    </div>
    <div id="content1">
<div ng-controller="ButtonsCtrl">
    <h4>Single toggle</h4>
    <pre>{{singleModel}}</pre>
    <button type cv="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="singleModel" btn-checkbox btn-checkbox-true="1" btn-checkbox-false="0">
        Single Toggle
    </button>
    <h4>Checkbox</h4>
    <pre>{{checkModel}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</button>
    </div>
    <h4>Radio</h4>
    <pre>{{radioModel}}</pre>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</button>
    </div>
</div>





<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple plunker forked from the AngularUI Bootstrap demo page (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/): http://plnkr.co/edit/frWpYAfC1TlZ13xNQzSV?p=preview

By comparing this plunker with your code you will notice that:

- you are not including angular-ui/bootstrap JavaScript (!)
- you need to add dependency on the `ui.bootstrap` module

On the other hand you are including Bootstrap's JavaScript which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome resource. Thanks!

Comment: Actually im using that exact code to test it now. I copied and pasted it over my previous code and even put the example.js file in the root directory with the index.html file. and I'm still getting the same result with the buttons as before. What could be causing it?